# jdbi jdbc vertica streaming result set for handling large data

Tags: jdbc, stream, vertica, jdbi

I am trying to connect to vertica through Jdbi jdbc to get huge result set.
Followed JDBI documentation and added this to dao,

```
@SqlQuery("<query>")
@Mapper(ResultRow.StreamMapper.class)
@FetchSize(chunkSizeInRows)
public Iterable<List<Object>> getStreamingResultSet(@Define("query") String query);
```

But it seems like its loading the entire data into memory instead of streaming it

[image]

Comment: Please add a question or you could post an issue to jdbi's page.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking at streaming result sets from JDBI, and came across this question. The answer is on the [SQL Object Queries documentation](https://jdbi.org/jdbi2/sql_object_api_queries/) page:

> because the method returns a `java.util.Iterator` it loads results
> lazily

So in this case, the `Iterable<List<Object>>` should be a `Iterator<List<Object>>` (I assume JDBI can convert a database row to a `List<Object>`).